# JavaScript Functionality

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function in which I would like to read an entire text file from my local computer. And store the entire file in a javascript variable. Then be able to return this variable to another function. I've researched different sites that said I could use XMLHttpRequest method to do so and I've tried using an absolute file path and relative file path. I just want a new set of eyes on the issue just in case I'm missing something smmall or completely off. The code is below

```
function setNewTexts()
        {
            var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            txtFile.open("GET", "textfile.txt", true);
            txtFile.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
              if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // document is ready to parse.
                if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // file is found
                  allText = txtFile.responseText; 
                  lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
                }
              }
            }
            txtFile.send(null);
            var text = "go go go ";
            return textFile;
        }
        value = setNewTexts();
```

Comment: What isn't working?  You never asked a question.  Also, the key letters in XMLHttpRequest are *Http*.  You can't use an absolute file path to some file on your system for security reasons.  The file you're retrieving needs to be available from your web server.

Comment: You can only get a local _File_ if a user selects it via an `<input type="file"/>`, you can then use [_FileReader_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to output the contents.

Comment: Are you running a local server, or running it from `file:///`?

Comment: Im running it from file ...

Comment: you need to use <input type=file> and FileReader() if you want any kind of portability...

Answer (score 1):

```
return textFile;
```

`textFile` is not defined. Everywhere else, you use the variable `txtFile`. Possibly a typo here. This could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/username/txtfile.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

This means that your browser, for security reasons, will not allow you to read files from outside your domain. In your case, `file:///`, you don't have a domain. Some older browsers allowed this, but that was the wild west of the web. You will need to run a server locally in order to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you would test your script on local computer (i.e. html file where script is running and textfile.txt are local) then you should remove the `if(txtFile.status === 200) { ... }` check as it is not always true in local runs even if file is really there.

And the main point. Since you intentionally made you request async (by passing `true`in `txtFile.open("GET", "textfile.txt", true);`) then you should change your function for example like follows:

```
function setNewTexts(callback) {        {
    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "textfile.txt", true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // document is ready to parse.
            if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // file is found
                var lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
                callback(lines);
            }
        }
    }
    txtFile.send(null);
}
```

And somewhere else where you need the content of the `textfile.txt`:

```
var value;
setNewTexts(function (lines) {
    value = lines;
});
```

The point is that since your request is async `onreadystatechange` handler will be executed after `setNewTexts` is done, i.e. you cannot access the `txtFile.responseText` right after `txtFile.send(null)` as there is no any reponse by that moment. The response (i.e. the content of the `textfile.txt`) will be available only when `onreadystatechange` will be invoked with `readyState === 4` and only in that moment you can save it into the `value` variable.